# Setting alpha of colorbar in MATLAB R2014b

Tags: matlab, alpha, colorbar

I have a colorplot (from imagesc) with an alpha map. I'd like the colorbar to reflect the alpha (notice that in the image below the colormaps are the same). I found solutions online but none seem to work in R2014b.

Code is here:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
A = imagesc(meshgrid(0:10,0:5));
alpha(A,1)
colorbar

subplot(2,1,2)
B = imagesc(meshgrid(0:10,0:5));
alpha(B,.7)
colorbar
```

[image: Same colormap - different alphas.]

James

Answer (score 1):

You could add a textbox with alpha on top of the colorbar. This works for later versions of MATLAB.

```
cb=colorbar

annotation('textbox',...
    cb.Position,...
    'FitBoxToText','off',...
    'FaceAlpha',0.5,...
    'EdgeColor',[1 1 1],...
    'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In pre-R2014b MATLAB, the `colorbar` is itself an axis containing an image for which you can set alpha:

```
hb = findobj(gcf,'Type','axes','Tag','Colorbar'); 
hi = findobj(hb,'Type','image');
alpha(hi,0.7)
```

Instead of `gcf`, use the handles of the individual subplots.

Or save its handle when you make it:

```
hb = colorbar;
```

From R2014b on, the colorbar is creating using the new handle graphics system, where there is no longer a child image to modify.  The `colorbar` is created internally with `colorbarHGUsingMATLABClasses`, which is an obfuscated .p file, so it's no clear how it's constructed.

Comment: I tried this one and it did nothing. Is this with R2014b?

Comment: @James Yes, R2014b.  I'll make a more complete example.  Perhaps I left out a detail.

Comment: @James Yikes!  On R2014b it's not clear how to do it.  Sorry I misunderstood the issue.