# Setting alpha of colorbar in MATLAB R2015b

Tags: matlab, alpha, colorbar

I would like to set some transparency in my plot which I can do with `alpha`. This works great but I also want to adapt the colorbar. Here is an example:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
A = imagesc(meshgrid(0:10,0:5));
alpha(A,1)
colorbar

subplot(2,1,2)
B = imagesc(meshgrid(0:10,0:5));
alpha(B,.1)
colorbar
```

The example is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240862/setting-alpha-of-colorbar-in-matlab-r2014b). On this page two solutions exists but none works for Matlab R2015b.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `hb = colorbar; alpha(hb, .1);`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, this does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With HG2 graphics (R2014b+) you can get some of the undocumented underlying plot objects and alter the transparency.

```
c = colorbar();

% Manually flush the event queue and force MATLAB to render the colorbar
% necessary on some versions
drawnow

alphaVal = 0.1;

% Get the color data of the object that correponds to the colorbar
cdata = c.Face.Texture.CData;

% Change the 4th channel (alpha channel) to 10% of it's initial value (255)
cdata(end,:) = uint8(alphaVal * cdata(end,:));

% Ensure that the display respects the alpha channel
c.Face.Texture.ColorType = 'truecoloralpha';

% Update the color data with the new transparency information
c.Face.Texture.CData = cdata;
```

[image]

You have to be careful doing this as the colorbar is continually refreshed and these changes will not stick. To get them to stay while I printed the figure, I just changed the `ColorBinding` mode of the `Face` to something besides `interpolated`

```
c.Face.ColorBinding = 'discrete';
```

This means that it won't be updated when you change color limits or the colormap. If you want to change either of those things you'll need to reset the `ColorBinding` to `intepolated` and then run the above code again.

```
c.Face.ColorBinding = 'interpolated';
```

For example, the following would save an image with a transparent colorbar for two colormaps:

```
c = colorbar();

drawnow;

alphaVal = 0.1;

% Make the colorbar transparent
cdata = c.Face.Texture.CData;
cdata(end,:) = uint8(alphaVal * cdata(end,:));
c.Face.Texture.ColorType = 'truecoloralpha';
c.Face.Texture.CData = cdata;

drawnow

% Make sure that the renderer doesn't revert your changes
c.Face.ColorBinding = 'discrete';

% Print your figure
print(gcf, 'Parula.png', '-dpng', '-r300');

% Now change the ColorBinding back
c.Face.ColorBinding = 'interpolated';

% Update the colormap to something new
colormap(jet);

drawnow

% Set the alpha values again
cdata = c.Face.Texture.CData;
cdata(end,:) = uint8(alphaVal * cdata(end,:));
c.Face.Texture.CData = cdata;

drawnow

% Make sure that the renderer doesn't revert your changes
c.Face.ColorBinding = 'discrete';

print(gcf, 'Ugly_colormap.png', '-dpng', '-r300');
```

Comment: Somehow this does not work for me. I'm getting the error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." because size(cdata ) = [0 0].

Comment: @machinery Hmmm strange. What OS?

Comment: I have Windows 10, 64-bit.

Comment: @machinery Are you trying to print or just display it as I did in the first example?

Comment: If I use `c = colorbar` instead of `c = colorbar();` it works but I don't see any effect on the colorbar. If I insert `c.Face.ColorBinding = 'discrete'; `directly after `c = colorbar`, I'm getting the warning "Warning: Error updating Quadrilateral. This feature is not yet implemented" and the colorbar is empty.

Comment: You want to call the `ColorBinding = 'discrete'` after everything else. If you're just displaying you don't actually even need that

Comment: I'm just trying to display, no printing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112836/discussion-between-suever-and-machinery).

Comment: Everything works except `c.Face.ColorBinding = 'discrete';` If I use it I'm getting "Warning: Error updating Quadrilateral.This feature is not yet implemented" in the print function and the colorbar is unchanged.

Comment: @machinery Yes as I said in the chat you will get this warning, but if you call a `drawnow` before calling that then it will "freeze" the colorbar in the new state.

Comment: @machinery I added some explicit drawnow commands to the last example

Comment: Is it possible to extend this colorbar hack to make it have more than one alpha value? I'd like to have multiple `patch` faces with different `FaceVertexAlphaData` values, but all in the same color. The colorbar then ideally should be of only that color, but saturated on one end and transparent (or white?) on the other. Can this be achieved somehow by extending the proposed methods?

Comment: @Erik Why not just use a custom colormap that maps from white to your solid color linearly?

Comment: @Suever Works for me! Try this MWE: `figure, p = patch([0, 1; 1, 2; 1, 2; 0, 1], [0, 1; 0, 1; 1, 2; 1, 2], [0, 1]); map = interp1([0, 1], [0, 0, 1; 1, 1, 1], linspace(1, 0, 256)); colormap(map), colorbar, line`. The last `line` command draws a line over one of the patch faces, just a test of mine to verify the order of graphics being drawn on top of each other.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. I have the funny problem that the code works fine outside a loop, but if I use the code inside a loop (generating a handful of figures at a time), the code doesn't work. No errors, just doesn't update the colorbar. Odd!

Comment: Hi @Suever. I am trying to implement your solution - I would like to save the figure as a png just as you demonstrated. I have tried to copy and run your code exactly as in the answer and it works well for changing the transparency. However, in the two exported png images the colorbars don't retain the transparency. In the actual Matlab figure itself the colorbar remains transparent after the export (so probably the "discrete" option is working). Can you help with what could be causing this? I am running R2017a. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution form Suever works however when working in the live editor (R2020b) I had to add:

```
set(gcf,'Visible','on')
```

This makes it such that the figure is plotted in an external pop up. Then it does work, but I do not know why.

Working example for live editor:

```
figure(1);clf;
set(gcf,'Visible','on')
c = colorbar();
drawnow;
alphaVal = 0.5;

% Make the colorbar transparent
cdata = c.Face.Texture.CData;
cdata(end,:) = uint8(alphaVal * cdata(end,:));
c.Face.Texture.ColorType = 'truecoloralpha';
c.Face.Texture.CData = cdata;
```