# Overlay two images with separate colormaps

Tags: image, matlab, overlay, matlab-figure

I'm working with some landsat tiff files in matlab and I would like to overlay a thermal heatmap over base imagery for a particular scene. The basemap is a grayscale image and for the thermal image I usually use a colormap of jet with a a limited display range.

For example, I'd usually create two figures to display side by side:

```
    figure
    imshow(temp,[-2,2])
    colormap jet

    figure 
    imshow(base)
```

where temp is an MxN array containing the temperature data and base is an MxN array containing the base image.

I'd prefer to have the temperature overlaying the base image in a single figure, like the one below. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use true color for your images rather than relying on the colormap. You can convert the values to the colormap values using `gray2ind` and `ind2rgb`.

```
% Just use grayscale for the base
hbase = ind2rgb(gray2ind(base), gray);

% Have the temperature use the builtin colormap 
hold on
htemp = imshow(temp, [-2,2]);
colormap jet
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for display, but of course, I've lost the real world information of temperatures and when I call colorbar I get the range of grayscale colors. Is there a way to preserve that so I can easily display a colorbar of temperatures?

Comment: @Amie Yea, you just switch which one uses the true color values. Updated the answer.

Comment: Right, but the true color values span 0-255, so the colorbar scale isn't displaying temperature values. Is there a way to map the colors back to the original temperatures?

Comment: @Amie Take a closer look at my edit. I don't convert temperatures to true color...

Comment: I see that, but for some reason the colorbar still displays 0-255. Cleared all the variables and ran this code:

hcolor = ind2rgb(gray2ind(base), gray);
hbase = imshow(hcolor);


hold on
htemp = imshow(temp);
colormap jet

alpha = 0.4;
set(htemp, 'AlphaData', alpha);

colorbar

Comment: @Amie What if you use `imagesc(temp)` instead of `imshow`?

Comment: @Sauver That doesn't seem to help. When I use imagesc it looks like the colorbar may be showing values that correspond to the mix of brightness from the base image and the color of the temperature. For example, the index value for a cell displays the correct temperature, but the color is 20-30 units higher on the colorbar scale.

Comment: @Amie Well you've specified a transparency value of 0.4 so the colors aren't going to correspond directly. Try setting no transparency to verify that it is correct.

Comment: If you need the colorbar to use transparent colors, maybe something like this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423603/setting-alpha-of-colorbar-in-matlab-r2015b/37423909#37423909

Comment: @Sauver, I figured it out. I was using imshow for the base image and getting a faulty colorbar. But if I use imagesc for both images, the colorbar provides the correct index values from temp. Thanks!